# Cómo elegir una cadena de conexión desde App.config- Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Requiero seleccionar en tiempo de ejecución una cadena de conexión declarada en el archivo app.config

El archivo app tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el formulario tengo un botón por medio del cual se determina qué cadena utilizar en base al valor seleccionado en un ComboBox:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If ComboBox1.Text = "PRUEBAS" Then

        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PRUEBA2ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Conn.Open()
        Reporte.Show()
        'Aquí hay una líneas(Que omití) donde se hace una consulta a la B.D.
        Conn.Close()

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "PRINCIPAL" Then

        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PRUEBAConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Conn.Open()
        Reporte.Show()
        'Aquí hay una líneas(Que omití) donde se hace una consulta a la B.D.
        Conn.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Al ejecutar el proyecto, al dar clic en el botón, luego de haber seleccionado un valor en el ComboBox, se muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error lo marca en cada línea de la conexión:

```
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PRUEBA2ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
```

Alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal? Alguna sugerencia sobre otra manera de seleccionar una cadena de conexión desde el App.config?

*ACTUALIZACIÓN DE LA PREGUNTA*

Ahora el detalle que tengo es que no selecciona la cadena que se le indica por medio del IF.

Independientemente de las cadenas de conexión del App.config está tomando por defecto la que está en el Designer del DataSet que estoy utilizando para cargar los datos.

```
Private Sub InitConnection()
    Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
    Me._connection.ConnectionString = Global.AppConfigProject.My.MySettings.Default.PRUEBA2ConnectionString
End Sub
```

Lo que puedo ver es que tiene una cadena asignada por default.

Hay alguna manera de indicarle que tome las cadenas que están en el Settings del proyecto? Es decir, estas cadenas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: algo en esa cadena es null. por favor, debuguea el programa, y vas a ver que uno de los objetos es nulo. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com//questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, me faltaba agregar Imports System.Configuration a la referencia del proyecto, por eso me mandaba el error.

Comment: no entiendo nada. apreta [edit] y agrega la informacion a la pregunta.

Comment: Listo, ya actualicé mi pregunta.

Comment: Ya se cual es tu probema. Que es reporte? Pq ese es el q tiene el designer seguro y nunca le estas actualizando la conexion. Abrir una conexion no quiere decir que todo tu programa la va a usar porque si. Cada objeto usa su propia conexion.

Comment: Reporte es el nombre del formulario que tiene asignado un ReportViewer para plasmar los datos del DataSet.

Comment: Claro pero no le estas pasando la cadena de conexion nueva nunca via codigo

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! Ya me percaté del error. En el reporte estoy usando un TableAdapter y es a éste al que debo pasarle la nueva cadena de conexión para que sepa cuál debe usar.